# How to use R package in python with importr package

Tags: python, r

I'm working on a web application using Dash, and I would like to use `arules` and `aruleViz` from R within a python script to get a graph of association rules obtained by using an Aprioi algorithm.

I found the `rpy2` package and I installed it using conda `conda install rpy2` ,then I try to import some packages like base tools by:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr`
arules = importr("tools",)`
```

That was fine(the package was imported)

And when I use: `arules = importr("arules",)` or `arules = importr("arulesViz",)`

I got receive the following error:

```
RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘arulesViz’
```

I saw an option in the `importr`package `(lib_loc=None)`. I'm not sure how can I change it.

If there is any way to solve this, or if you know of a package in python that will help me plot a graph with vertices (I know how to so that with `matplot.lib` library using scatter but i'm not happy with it) I would greatly appreciate the help!

Thank you!

Comment: Install the arulesviz package

Comment: @HongOoi, Did you mean `arulesViz` it's already installed ! and i was using it with `arules` in R.

Answer (score 0):

R packages must be installed before `rpy2` can hope to find them. rpy2's `importr()` relies on R's own package loading system.

If you are certain to have installed that package earlier, you might have installed it in different directory, in a previous R process, and your current R process does not know about that directory. The optional named argument `lib_loc` accepts the path to that directory (see the [doc](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#rpy2.robjects.packages.importr)).

(Note that there is also a utility function to [check if an R package is installed](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#rpy2.robjects.packages.isinstalled) without loading it)